# eMail from Python3 using 1and1 Ionos account

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I want to generate an email from within Python3 code.  I can get it to work using a gmail account but not with my 1and1 Ionos account.  This is the code

```
import smtplib

MAIL_2 = ['test@sulley.info']
FROM_ADDR = 'mick@sulley.info'
SUBJECT = 'Mail Subject via Ionos`'
BODY = 'Body of message'
PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
SMTP_SERVER = "smtp.ionos.co.uk:587"
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(FROM_ADDR, PASSWORD)
header = 'To:' + ", ".MAIL_2 + '\n' + 'From: ' + FROM_ADDR + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + SUBJECT + '\n'
mmsg = header + '\n' + SUBJECT + '\n' + BODY + '\n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(FROM_ADDR, MAIL_2,mmsg)
smtpserver.close()
```

The error message is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmail-ionos01.py", line 14, in <module>
    smtpserver.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 783, in starttls
    self.sock = context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER] sslv3 alert illegal parameter (_ssl.c:1131)
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: I contacted Ionos support gave them the info above and this is the message i had back from them

    Our SMTP details are available here: https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/index.php?id=2490

    Based on the error message I have seen in the evidence you've provided my advice for a similar issue on a server would be to check the reverse dns, server hostname, and make sure your domain SPF record is configured correctly. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful.

I have looked at reverse dns and domain SPF records, but still have no idea.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Assembling an email message from simple strings is brittle and error-prone. Your code works (by accident, by the looks of it) for simple English messages, but will not produce a valid email message for any nontrivial input.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, it worked with me, you need to put the address of ionos server where you host your domain with, in my case it is Spain:

```
#send email
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
server  = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.es', 587)
try:
    name="Name" #You need to fill the name here
    server.connect('smtp.ionos.es', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("Youremailhostedonionos","password")
    TOADDR   = "address@domain.com"
    FromADDR = "Youremailhostedonionos"
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "email subject here"
    msg['From'] = FromADDR
    msg['To']      = TOADDR
    #The below is email body
    html = """\
                <html>
                  <body>
                    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">Dear {0},</span></p>
                   <p>
                      your email body
                    </p>
                    <p>Kind Regards,<br />
                    Your name ....
                    </p>
                    </body>
                </html>
                """.format(name.split()[0])
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
    server.sendmail(FromADDR, TOADDR, msg.as_string())
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Comment: It looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I had managed to get something working, but this code looks more complete and robust than mine.  I will also look at the EmailMessage API and see if I can figure that out.  I appreciate your help, thank you.  Mick